# Django How to check if entry exists in database?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model in my application:

```
class Device(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "devices"

    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
    rule = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, imei, last_update, rule):
        device = cls(imei = imei, last_update = last_update, rule = rule)
        return device

    def __str__(self):
        return self.imei
```

Now, after I do an update I want to check if the device is already stored in my database. So I used this code:

```
def deviceUpdate(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    imei = json_data['imei']
    date = json_data['updateDate']
    rule = json_data['rule']

    if Device.objects.filter(imei="123456789").exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But for some reason when I run it, it doesn't work and I keep getting 500 error. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
This is the error that I get:
**AttributeError at /policies/update
'bool' object has no attribute 'status_code'**

**Edit 2**
I found the problem, I forgot that I am supposed to return response object.
Instead I was returning boolean.

Comment: use `get_or_create` instead

Comment: Fix the else: indentation.

Comment: Can you add the traceback of the error and rest of the function where you run the `exists` method?

Comment: @ikkuh I edited the question a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your view is returning a `HttpResponse` object, not just "True" or "False". E.g.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def deviceUpdate(request):
    ...
    return JsonResponse(True, safe=False)
```